# Add filename as an attribute while reading multiple csv w/ lapply (or add filename at bind_rows step)

Tags: r, lapply

**EDIT:**

Using the following solved my problem:

```
bind_rows(setNames(df, basename(files)), .id = "id")
```

Faster summary of problem:
Wanting to add an attribute for the file name while combining multiple csv files w/ lapply, read_csv, and bind_rows. Because .id pulls the names from the original data frame, I wasn't sure how to change it preemptively... but basename() serves that function.

Here, 'files' refers to the list of file names for my data.

**ORIGINAL POST:**
I have a number of csv files where the column names is on the fifth row. So right now I'm skipping the first four so all the files will have the same column structure. However, I want to add a column with an ID tag that's the name of that csv file. If it's any easier, the name of the file is repeated in one of the skipped cells in the first four rows.

**Right now my code is this:**

To create the list of file names

```
folder = "my\\desktop\\path"
files = list.files(
  path = folder,
  pattern = "_indicator.*csv$",
  recursive = TRUE,    # include subfolders 
  ignore.case = T,
  full.names = T
)
```

To read all the files

```
df <-
  lapply(files, function(i){
  read.csv(i, header=TRUE, skip=4)
  })
```

They read in as one data frame of 70 different lists, all containing 15 rows and 76 columns.
This is all good, this is correct. I got to this point by reading other stack overflow questions.

However, I ultimately want to combine them into one dataframe, not one dataframe of lists.

I'm thinking about doing this:

```
df <- bind_rows(df.list, .id = "id")
```

***I then get the data structure I want, but the id is just a number. I still have my list of file names... so I could use the mutate function and change the id number to the file name (assuming it's still in the same order). But that just feels really inefficient. Is there a way to make the indicator my filename at the bind_rows or read_csv step?

I understand that .id is using the names from my original data frame of lists... but I don't know how to use lapply / read_csv to create that original data frame w/ filenames instead of numbers... or even if that's the best approach***

Comment: The `.id` in `bind_rows()` is copied from the names of your list elements.  If they are unnamed, then it gives the index.  So the obvious approach is to name the list elements before binding them.

Comment: I don't know how to do that. This data frame is really nested, and I've only used the mutate function on less nested data frames, so I'm not sure how I go about naming the list elements. That was part of my question... because I don't know how to do that renaming in the original form, I'm thinking about mutating it at the end, but I know that's inefficient

Comment: Try `bind_rows(setNames(df.list, basename(files)), .id = "id")`.  If that doesn't work you will need to give a minimal and reproducible example of your data so we can see what is going on.